# RewriteRule cannot compile regular expression in VPS

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My previous server working fine. Today I changed new server and getting RewriteRule cannot compile regular expression on my htaccess.

How to fix this line

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s\$\:\!\?\[\]\(\)\'\"]+)$ %{QUERY_STRING}?file=$1 [L]
```

This is rule which rewrite all page to index.php file. I am using Apache 2.2.29. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex indeed looks suspect, try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([][\w\s$:!()'"-]+)/?$ ?file=$1 [L,QSA]
```

- hyphen needs to be at first or last position in character class to avoid escaping.
- No need to do all that escaping inside a character class.

Comment: Thank you for helping me ! However, it doesn't work. When I access http://mywebsite.com/hello, it showed "not found". I want to rewrite URL to index.php.